# How to install Radeon drivers on Loki

Tags: graphic-drivers

So I just changed to Linux and I've been mostly without problems, but I've had some trouble installing drivers in this system, I have the model R7 260X/360 and I downloaded the drivers from [this link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux) and when I installed a rebooted it frozed even before the user screen, so I had to reinstall elementary again twice.
I'd like to install them as I play often, but I can't install STEAM neither, it just doesn't run after installing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat. My GPU is the R9 M370X, so not exactly the same, but close.

The official proprietary drivers have been abandoned by AMD. As far as I know they just aren't working on Loki, period. There are open source drivers but I've not been able to get anything working, including the drivers you can get from that link.

It's also been suggested elsewhere to upgrade the kernel from 4.4 to something newer, which I've also done, and also without success.

The eOS devs aren't offering us much here except the suggestion to only use Intel GPUs. Other than that, it looks like for the time being there's not really a  solution for our problem.

Comment: I installed the "additional drivers" sofware, and it seems that it has some sort of drivers going on, I just installed Tyranny and it ran almost perfectly, but I haven't tried heavier games.